# How to fill in optional function arguments automatically with corresponding dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, arguments

Let's say I have a function in Python:

```
def foo(x,a=".",b=2):
    ...
```

and I have a dictionary:

```
param_dict = {'a':'!', 'b':5}
```

How would I be able to communicate the values in `param_dict` to `foo`, matching the corresponding dictionary key to the argument name, and do so in an automatic way?  (i.e., not manually writing out `foo(x,a=param_dict['a'],b=param_dict['b'])`)

Also would like it so that if the corresponding key isn't found in `param_dict`, the default value of the argument is kept.

Comment: What about passing the entire dictionary to `foo`!

Answer (score 1):

`foo(x, **param_dict)` Should work

Comment: If the dictionary had keys that didn't match any of the arguments in the function, would the function just ignore them or would there be an error?

Comment: An error, to avoid it: `def foo(x,a=".",b=2, **rest):`